# Apache SSL timeout is not matching settings

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, timeout, https

I have a CentOS 6.7 apache Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Unix) server with both http and https  ports configured. They are configured the same, except for the SSL specific settings.

The most relevant settings being

```
KeepAlive on
MaxKeepAliveRequests 50
KeepAliveTimeout 65
Timeout 65
AcceptFilter https none
```

There are no .htaccess files or other obvious configuration files.

But when I test the raw connection timeout with a command like

## time telnet localhost 443       or   # time telnet localhost 80

I get unexpected and wrong results.

For http I get

```
time telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

real    0m51.423s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

And for SSL https I get

```
time telnet localhost 443
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.

real    0m20.018s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.002s
```

As you can see, nigther is showing the expected 65 second timeout, http is 50 seconds and https is 20 seconds.

No where in any of the config files is an alternative timeout set.

I also considered the kernel TCP settings.
tcp_fin_timeout=60
tcp_keepalive_time=7200
tcp_synack_retries=5

Where is this 20 seconds for SSL coming from? Why is the keepalive settings and timeout settings being ignored? Is there a different form of 'KeepAlive' and/or 'Timeout' keywords for SSL that makes it differ from http?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are on Linux, the [`AcceptFilter`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#acceptfilter) feature is using the `TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT` socket option on Linux.  The Apache source code shows that `httpd` uses a socket option value of 30 seconds (hardcoded) for this.

***If*** your Apache *also* has the `mod_reqtimeout` module, it could be that the default behavior of [`RequestReadTimeout`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html#requestreadtimeout) is involved.  By default, `RequestReadTimeout` waits *at least* 20 seconds for reading headers before it times out the client connection.

So taking these together, *maybe* you see 50 secs timeout for HTTP requests because you have *not* disabled the `AcceptFilter` for HTTP (just HTTPS), which means you have 30 secs (`AcceptFilter`) plus 20 secs (`RequestReadTimeout`).  *But* for HTTPS requests, where you have disabled the `AcceptFilter`, I suspect you are encountering *just* the 20 secs timeout due to `RequestReadTimeout`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have **reqtimeout** apache module loaded?

Try this command to see: `apachectl -M | grep reqtimeout`

If so, it's got the 20 second default as per http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html:

> Syntax:   RequestReadTimeout [header=timeout[-maxtimeout][,MinRate=rate]
>    [body=timeout[-maxtimeout][,MinRate=rate]
>
> Default:  header=20-40,MinRate=500 body=20,MinRate=500

---

You can **change** this to 60 seconds (90 max including accepting requests) with the following in your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf (or some vhosts.conf kind of file):

`RequestReadTimeout header=60-90,MinRate=500 body=60-90,MinRate=500`

---

You can also **test** it before/after with the following command:

`time openssl s_client -connect your.ip.address.here:443`

For me:

BEFORE

```
real    0m20.222s
user    0m0.012s
sys 0m0.000s
```

AFTER

```
real    1m0.527s
user    0m0.017s
sys 0m0.006s
```